# Merge tags "web-crawler", "crawl", "crawler", "spider"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I would like these tags to be merged under "web-crawler". This is how it now stands.
[web-crawler](/questions/tagged/web-crawler) (1,073 questions).
[crawl](/questions/tagged/crawl) (130 questions).
[crawler](/questions/tagged/crawler) (344 questions).
[spider](/questions/tagged/spider) (208 questions).
Tag wiki for spider says "Synonym for web-crawler tag".

Comment: The Cthulhu god is crawling around.

Comment: Don't forget [tag:spider-man].

Comment: I think the [[crawling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crawling)] tag should also be added to this list

Answer (score 3):

The author of [this recently-suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2674860) agrees that the 'crawl' tag covers the same ground. I rejected the edit to avoid duplicate tags, but a cleanup is definitely needed. I plan to start retagging these as time allows and would welcome additional help.